Proving two simple properties of the Jacobi $\vartheta$ Nullwert functions
I'm struggling to find any sources where these two properties of $\vartheta_3$ and $\vartheta_4$ are proved, and I could not prove it myself either.
To be precise, I am talking about
$$\vartheta_3(q) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2} \hskip2em\text{and}\hskip2em \vartheta_4(q) = \vartheta_3(-q) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n q^{n^2}\hskip2em\text{for}\ q\in\mathbb{C}, |q|<1\ .$$
First, by looking at a plot it seems that $\vartheta_3(q)$ is strictly increasing on the real line, or, to be more precise, $\vartheta_3'(q) \geq 1$. For $q \in [0,1)$, this is obvious. But I was unable to prove it for $q < 0$.
Second, it is not too hard to show that $\text{agm}(\vartheta_3(q)^2, \vartheta_4(q)^2) = 1$ for $q\in(-1,1)$ where $\text{agm}$ is the arithmetic–geometric mean. However, to lift this to complex $q$ via analytic continuation, one needs to show that $\vartheta_3(q)^2 / \vartheta_4(q)^2 \notin \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ since the AGM has a branch cut there.
Is it the case that $\vartheta_3(q)^2 / \vartheta_4(q)^2$ is never a non-positive real? One can probably get the non-vanishing from the Jacobi triple product, but I don't see a way to prove that it isn't negative.

I wonder if some elliptic function identities help. If $k$ is the elliptic modulus, then it is known that
$$
k=4q^{1/2}\prod_{n\ge1}\left(1+q^{2n}\over1+q^{2n-1}\right)^4={\vartheta_2(q)^2\over\vartheta_3(q)^2}
$$
and
$$
k':=\sqrt{1-k^2}=\prod_{n\ge1}\left(1-q^{2n-1}\over1+q^{2n-1}\right)^4={\vartheta_4(q)^2\over\vartheta_3(q)^2}.
$$

I'm starting to suspect the Jacobi triple product is the key. I'll have a look at that soon.

This is called inversion problem and is described in detail in Elliptic Functions by Armitage and Eberlein in Chapter 5, Section 5.2, page 108. The key result is that if $m$ is a complex number with $m\notin [1, \infty) $ and $m\notin (-\infty, 0]$ then the integrals $K(m) =\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-m\sin^2x)^{-1/2},dx,K(1-m)$ are well defined and then $\tau=iK(1-m)/K(m)$ has positive imaginary part and is a solution to $m=\vartheta_2^4(q)/\vartheta_3^4(q)$ where $q=\exp(\pi i\tau) $.

That sounds promising. Thanks! And, indeed, proving that $\vartheta_3(q)$ is strictly increasing on the real line is trivial using the Jacobi triple product.

As I suspected in my comment, the answer to the first question is simply to use the Jacobi triple product.
It is clear from the infinite sum definition that $\vartheta_3$ is strictly increasing on the non-negative reals.
Using the Jacobi triple product, one can also see that $\vartheta_4(q) = \vartheta_3(-q)$ is strictly decreasing on the non-negative reals: We have
$$\vartheta_4(q) = (q^2; q^2)_\infty\ \big((q; q^2)_\infty\big)^2 = \prod_{n=0}^\infty (1-q^{2n+2})(1-q^{2n+1})^2$$
and it is clear that each of the three factors in the infinite product is a strictly decreasing positive function in the range $q\in[0,1)$.
 
As for the $\vartheta_3(q)^2/\vartheta_4(q)^2$ never being a non-positive real, that seems to be wrong. The following Mathematica plot shows that e.g. for $q \approx 0.322397(1+i)$ we have $\vartheta_3(q)^2/\vartheta_4(q)^2 \approx -0.17157$.
Plot[{Arg[EllipticTheta[3,(1+I)x]^2/EllipticTheta[4,(1+I)x]^2]}, { x,0,0.7}]

So it seems that one really has to pay attention to branch cuts when talking about the relationship between the Jacobi theta functions and the complex AGM.
